# Sympy's latex printer, folding short fractions

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I'm feeding `sympy.latex` a string involving fractions and I'd like to get its latex representation with fractions "folded", i.e., typeset as 3/2 rather than as \frac{3}{2}. I'm setting the `fold_short_fractions` keyword argument to `True`, but the results I'm getting are inconsistent:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_exp
>>> from sympy import latex
>>>
>>> print(latex(parse_expr("3*x**2/y"))) # OK
\frac{3 x^{2}}{y}
>>> print(latex(parse_expr("3*x**2/y"), fold_short_frac=True)) # OK
3 x^{2} / y
>>>
>>> print(latex(parse_expr("3/2"))) # OK
\frac{3}{2}
>>> print(latex(parse_expr("3/2"), fold_short_frac=True)) # No!!
\frac{3}{2}
```

As you can see, it refuses to fold the numerical fraction 3/2, although it seems to be okay with symbolic expressions. Does anyone have an explanation/fix/workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug in the LaTeX printer. Specifically, it ignores this setting for rational numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the SymPy latex printer. It isn't looking at the `fold_short_frac` option for rational numbers. I've got a fix [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/11497).

In the meantime, you can use this is as workaround:

```
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter

class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_Rational(self, expr):
        if expr.q != 1:
            sign = ""
            p = expr.p
            if expr.p < 0:
                sign = "- "
                p = -p
            if self._settings['fold_short_frac']:
                return r"%s%d / %d" % (sign, p, expr.q)
            return r"%s\frac{%d}{%d}" % (sign, p, expr.q)
        else:
            return self._print(expr.p)

def latex(expr, **settings):
    return MyLatexPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)
```